# 550 Verification failed Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command)

Tags: postfix, email-bounces, verification

*Note: email addresses, domains, and ip addresses have been changed to protect the innocent*

Current Error:

`Apr 28 23:47:32 vps01 postfix/smtp[8012]: 2A03D6285EF9: to=<brian@somedomain.com>, relay=mail.somedomain.com[162.144.93.233]:25, delay=42, delays=0.01/0.02/21/21, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.somedomain.com[162.144.93.233] said: 550-Verification failed for <test@mydomain.org> 550-The mail server could not deliver mail to test@mydomain.org.  The account or domain may not exist, they may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries. 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))`

I am trying to get email working for a client with several domains on a vps running Ubuntu Server and Apache2. Server has IspConfig 3 installed if it makes any difference to anybody.

I am able to receive and send emails to most of the domains that I have tried so far except one in particular. Others are probably failing that are unknown to me.

I was receiving an error `550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)` but I have been able to fix that as far as I know by creating rDNS record and changing my hostname in postfix to my FQDN. This has proceeded to my current error.

I have followed the guide at https://www.howtoforge.com/hardening-postfix-for-ispconfig-3 to harden my postfix to prevent spam.

I have reviewed [Postfix Sender Verification 550](https://serverfault.com/questions/627417/postfix-sender-verification-550) and checked my MX records but it appears to me that everything is set correctly.

```
dig mydomain.org MX

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9ubuntu0.5-Ubuntu <<>> mydomain.org MX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18363
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.org.             IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.org.      1199    IN      MX      10 55.55.55.55. (ip address changed for security purposes)

;; Query time: 44 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 28 23:54:59 CDT 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 75
```

I have been using http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%3amydomain.org&run=toolpage# to check for problems along the way as well, but the only insight it is giving me know appears to be longer connection and transaction time which I believe is due to configuring postscreen.

Full mail.log for time period during errors

```
Apr 29 00:24:44 vps01 postfix/smtpd[9021]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Apr 29 00:24:44 vps01 postfix/smtpd[9021]: DA4326285EF9: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Apr 29 00:24:44 vps01 postfix/cleanup[9013]: DA4326285EF9: message-id=<79da838b66dd1fd030bfe64355ca8d42@mydomain.org>
Apr 29 00:24:44 vps01 postfix/smtpd[9021]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Apr 29 00:24:44 vps01 postfix/qmgr[7860]: DA4326285EF9: from=<test@mydomain.org>, size=1671, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 29 00:24:44 vps01 amavis[8496]: (08496-10) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, <test@mydomain.org> -> <brian@somedomain.com>, Message-ID: <79da838b66dd1fd030bfe64355ca8d42@mydomain.org>, mail_id: aJjfGa_rtNVH, Hits: -0.101, size: 1145, queued_as: DA4326285EF9, dkim_sd=dkim:mydomain.org, 399 ms
Apr 29 00:24:44 vps01 postfix/smtp[9018]: 669CD6285BEA: to=<brian@somedomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.5, delays=0.08/0.02/0/0.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as DA4326285EF9)
Apr 29 00:24:44 vps01 postfix/qmgr[7860]: 669CD6285BEA: removed
Apr 29 00:25:01 vps01 postfix/postscreen[9069]: CONNECT from [::1]:44502 to [::1]:25
Apr 29 00:25:01 vps01 postfix/postscreen[9069]: WHITELISTED [::1]:44502
Apr 29 00:25:01 vps01 postfix/smtpd[9071]: connect from localhost[::1]
Apr 29 00:25:01 vps01 postfix/smtpd[9071]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[::1]
Apr 29 00:25:01 vps01 postfix/smtpd[9071]: disconnect from localhost[::1]
Apr 29 00:25:27 vps01 postfix/smtp[9022]: DA4326285EF9: to=<brian@somedomain.com>, relay=mail.somedomain.com[162.144.93.233]:25, delay=43, delays=0.01/0.01/22/21, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.somedomain.com[162.144.93.233] said: 550-Verification failed for <test@mydomain.org> 550-The mail server could not deliver mail to test@mydomain.org.  The account or domain may not exist, they may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries. 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Apr 29 00:25:27 vps01 postfix/cleanup[9013]: D2C3E6285EFA: message-id=<20160429052527.D2C3E6285EFA@mn-vps-01.cbcmcalester.com>
Apr 29 00:25:27 vps01 postfix/qmgr[7860]: D2C3E6285EFA: from=<>, size=4219, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 29 00:25:27 vps01 postfix/bounce[9112]: DA4326285EF9: sender non-delivery notification: D2C3E6285EFA
Apr 29 00:25:27 vps01 postfix/qmgr[7860]: DA4326285EF9: removed
Apr 29 00:25:27 vps01 dovecot: lda(test@mydomain.org): sieve: msgid=<20160429052527.D2C3E6285EFA@mn-vps-01.cbcmcalester.com>: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'
Apr 29 00:25:27 vps01 postfix/pipe[9113]: D2C3E6285EFA: to=<test@mydomain.org>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.06, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Apr 29 00:25:27 vps01 postfix/qmgr[7860]: D2C3E6285EFA: removed
Apr 29 00:25:28 vps01 postfix/anvil[8945]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtpd:64.20.227.137) at Apr 29 00:22:05
Apr 29 00:25:28 vps01 postfix/anvil[8945]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtpd:64.20.227.137) at Apr 29 00:22:05
Apr 29 00:25:28 vps01 postfix/anvil[8945]: statistics: max message rate 1/60s for (smtpd:64.20.227.137) at Apr 29 00:22:07
Apr 29 00:25:28 vps01 postfix/anvil[8945]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Apr 29 00:22:05
```

It appears that I did not receive the `RCPT TO` command to verify the user. I have researched online that trying to resolve this is a waste of time and should just tell the receiving domain to turn off verifying users but this is not an available option.

**UPDATE**

OK, I have made the DNS changes and new mx record host @ points to mail.mydomain.org. I have already created A record for mail to point to my ip address. I will wait for dns to propogate and try again.

Comment: You should not use ip address in the MX record - ```IN MX 10 63.142.252.80.```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a really strange setup

```
telnet mail.abcgreenbrier.org 25
Trying 63.142.252.80...
Connected to mail.abcgreenbrier.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mn-vps-01.cbcmcalester.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
helo localhost
250 mn-vps-01.cbcmcalester.com
mail from:<>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:<test@abcgreenbrier.org>
450 4.2.0 <test@abcgreenbrier.org>: Recipient address rejected: Greylisted, see http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/help/abcgreenbrier.org.html
```

Why are you greylisting your own domain?

Comment: It was recommended to me to enable greylisting although I have never been fond of its operation. I installed postgrey and then edited main.cf and added `check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023` to the end of smtpd_recipient_restrictions:. I am not sure how it should be setup correctly it is currently disabled.

Comment: @amaster507 Greylisting will definitely cause sender verify to fail. There's not much you can do about this. While greylisting is a fairly reasonable thing to do if you get lots of spam, sender verify never has been something you can do reliably. I'm a little surprised to hear that someone is still doing it.

Comment: After fixing my DNS issues as was commented to the question and disabling greylisting emails are being received and sent correctly.